# Branch IO and Facebook ads - Facebook has changed ad setup

Tags: android, facebook, branch, branch.io

I am trying to setup deferred deep links by following this guide: https://help.branch.io/using-branch/docs/facebook-app-install-ads

However, on the screenshots in the guide when the ad is setup, the guide is refering the the "Deep Link" input box as the place where you put the deferred deep link. When I try to setup the ad and choose application install as the target of the ad, I only get the "Deferred Deep Link" input box which requires a format of appschema://url.

I've seen dozens of reports in the last couple of months that this approach is just not working and is returning null when the deferred deep link is followed this way.

Can you suggest something else or at least a modification to the setup?

So the testing goes like this:

1) Have a live ad campaign that has the deferred deep link

2) Click on that ad on the mobile device -> It redirects to the store -> Install the app -> Run the app

3) The deferred link is null :(

4) If I click on the ad once I have the app installed, it correctly fetches the deferred link using the handler: fetchDeferredAppLinkData

I've checked the manifest configuration and the code seems fine, otherwise the deep link wouldn't load the app. I've also setup a firebase deep link and tried to recreate the same funnel by manually clicking on the firebase deep link and it correctly installed the application and I was able to use the deferred link data using Firebase SDK.

There's clearly something wrong with the FB SDK and the Branch IO docs looks outdated.

Answer (score 0):

As I can understand from the presented query, that you are currently facing issues for deferred deep linking via Facebook where you are not receiving the deferred deep link data.
This is currently a global issue with Facebook where all deferred deeplinks are failing. You can refer to the Github link here : https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk/issues/611
We have raised this with the Facebook team and the concerned team is looking into it. We do not have any ETA at this very moment.
You can keep a check on the above Github link for any updates.